# What prayers should one recite in times of great fear?

Tags: tefilla, blessing, emotions

During situations of great fear, we tend to look to God for comfort and guidance to free us from those fears. I was curious if there was a specific prayer related to fear and being freed from fear that one could recite for comfort?

In context:

When I say fear, I do not mean danger. If I thought I was in danger I would say the Shema as I would be uncertain of my life outcome.

I'm specifying you're safe but experiencing great fear or uncertainty but you aren't at risk of death. Such as a phobia or similar harmless activity.

Answer (score 4):

It is interesting that you mention Shema as a defense for danger ,but from the gemara in Sanhedrin 94a we see that it is an antidote for fear as well.

Text and translation from Seferia:

אמר רבינא ש"מ האי מאן דמבעית אף על גב דאיהו לא חזי מזליה חזי

Ravina said: Conclude from it that in the case of this person who becomes frightened with no apparent cause, although he does not see what causes his fear, his guardian angel sees it

מאי תקנתיה לינשוף מדוכתיה ארבעה גרמידי אי נמי ליקרי קרית שמע ואי קאי במקום הטנופת לימא הכי עיזא דבי טבחא שמינא מינאי

What is his remedy? Let him leap four cubits from his current location to distance himself from the perceived danger. Alternatively, let him recite Shema, which will afford him protection. And if he is standing in a place of filth, where it is prohibited to recite verses from the Torah, let him say this formula: The goat of the slaughterhouse is fatter than I, and let the demon harm the goat instead.

I have also seen from the sefer Segulas Yisrael a few segulos for one who is struck with fear.

Comment: The gemara here seems to link fear with danger, they go together .

Comment: Genuinely wasn't aware of this. I always associated the Shema as something specific to life or death situations or uncertainty around life and death. (Speaking it before bed and before death if you have the opportunity) - I appreciate the new knowledge.